# EmailMessage Status is not changed to "Read"

Tags: partner-communities, partner-portal, email2case, emailmessage, status

I have enabled email-to-case functionality and I have a user with **Partner Community** license. He works on **Partner Portal**. When he opens an e-mail through the Partner Portal its status is not updated to "Read" (It is still in "New" status). However if Salesforce user opens the e-mail, the status is automatically updated to "Read".

Has anyone spotted similar issue? Are there any special permissions which need to be enabled for Partner Community user to invoke changing EmailMessage status?

EDIT:
This issue occurs only for third party e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

I have rised a case to Salesforce Support and got the following answer:

> Hi,
>
> I have received a feedback that this is working as designed. Currently this is still on the process of being updated. I have tried to seek supporting articles but could not find one. And this seems to be a a limitation of the coding. But our Research and Development Team is welcome to future changes and additional capabilities to our Standard Features.
>
> We also did a test on our end and this is also happening to me. With this being said, I will be closing the case for now as your query has already been answered. If further clarification is needed, feel free to raise another case and we will be more than happy to assist.

I rised the following idea:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CQ9wQAG

If you are struggling with familiar issue - please upvote. :) If Salesforce will take it into consideration the problem will hopefully be fixed.

Of course if you have found better solution to my problem - do not hesitate to answer!

Answer (score 0):

If any new emailmessage is coming salesforce create record in the emailmessage object with status '0' (new) . if any one read email  or used workflow or trigger on emailmessage object  above status automatically turn into Read (1)  record is updated  I think this is defect on saleforce causing lot of issues in my place. 
if you replay to the email new record is inserted into emailmessage  with status '3'(Replied).. I think sales force need to insert record when email is read not updating the status .. I am sure it is going to be same behavior in dealing with Emailmessage object.